# Add a vertex in the middle of a path with d3js

Tags: d3.js

How can I modify a path according to user actions? 
For example: I have a path composed of three points A, B and C. When the user clicks on the path (somewhere other than an existing point) I would like add a new point at that position to the path. How can I insert the new point into the path at the correct location?

[Here you can find an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6bh7b/)

```
var nodes = [[30, 130], [250, 250], [400,130]];

var line = d3.svg.line();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 5000);

var path = svg.append("path")
            .datum(nodes)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .call(update);

path.on("click", insertNode);

function update() {
  svg.select("path").attr("d", line);

  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d; });
}

function insertNode(data) {
     //create the new node:
   var newNode = [];


   var newNode = d3.mouse(svg.node());
       //find coordinates relative to the plotting region

   nodes.push(newNode); //add to your nodes array


   update();
}
```

If you click on the first segment (sx -> dx) a new segment is added from the end of the path to the new node because I add the new node at the end of the nodes array.The right behavior is a new node in the path (nodes array) between the nodes [30, 130] and [250, 250]

Thanks!
aGO!

Comment: You would need to convert the click coordinates into the corresponding data points and then redraw the lines.

Comment: This is simple but the problem is to know if the new node is between A end B or B and C to give the right order

Comment: What is the order? Is it smaller coordinates to larger ones? Then just compare those.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand...can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply add the new node to the array, you have to determine its position first. One way of doing this is to compute the angle to all points. When the absolute values are the same, you know that you've found your insert position. The only snag is that because of the width of the line, it won't be exactly 180 degrees, so you have to account for that. The following code attempts this and splices the new node into the array.

```
var idx = 0, prevAngle;
nodes.forEach(function(n, i) {
    var angle = Math.abs(Math.atan((n[1] - newNode[1]) / (n[0] - newNode[0])));
    if(Math.abs(angle - prevAngle) < 0.05) {
        idx = i;
    }
    prevAngle = angle;
});

tmp = nodes.slice(0, idx);
tmp.push(newNode);
nodes = tmp.concat(nodes.slice(idx));
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6bh7b/8/).

Comment: That's why I asked you what the order is. Do you want to order by x or y coordinates? For y, see http://jsfiddle.net/6bh7b/5/

Comment: No order that's why I didn't understand your previus response. I would like add a node where I click on the path

Comment: How do you determine where the node that is added is put in the sequence of nodes? Note that it doesn't make sense to add a node *on* the path as you would get exactly the same path.

Comment: I would like add a node on the path where I clicked because then I will connect another path to this one by this node...like a graph

Answer (score 0):

The link's data object contains the source and target node data objects, so you can use that information to split the link in two, connected through the new node.

Sample code, assuming `linkElements` is your d3 selection of the link `<path>` or `<line>` elements, and `links` and `nodes` are the data arrays corresponding to `force.links()` and `force.nodes()`:

```
linkElements.on("click", insertNode);

function insertNode(linkData){ //parameter is the *link's* data object

   //create the new node:
   var newNode = {};

   var clickPoint = d3.mouse(this.parentNode);
       //find coordinates relative to the plotting region

   newNode.x = xScale.invert(clickPoint[0]);
   newNode.y = yScale.invert(clickPoint[1]);
       //convert coordinates to data values

   nodes.push(newNode); //add to your nodes array


   //create a new link for the second half of the old link:
   var newLink = {source:newNode, target:linkData.target};

   links.push(newLink); //add to your links array

   //update the old link to point to the new node:
   linkData.target = newNode;

   update();
}
```

This of course only updates the *data objects* for the nodes and links, your `update()` function will have to update the force layout and create the entering SVG elements.

Comment: I haven't specified anything about the type of svg element -- this is only changing the data objects.  It's up to you whether the links are drawn as paths or as lines in your update() method.  You would draw them with the exact same steps as in your initialization method, just being careful to separate out your `enter()` and `exit()` chains from your update chain.  However, I will warn you that the *shape* of a curved path won't necessarily match the shapes of the two curves you create from it.  Try putting it together as a sample fiddle, and if you have any problems come back.

Comment: @aGO: Sorry, I realize I had confused things in the sample code by using the variable name `links` for two different things; I've clarified it now.

Comment: I create e js fiddle to explain better my problem http://jsfiddle.net/6bh7b/ thank you!

Comment: Okay, this is something quite different from what I thought you meant.  When you said "nodes" I assumed you were using a force or tree layout with distinct nodes or links.  I don't have time to answer, but I'm going to edit your question to be more clear so someone else can help.